# Multiple Git repositories in a Theia workspace

Tags: git, theia

I have a workspace in which I have added several folders, each of them having its own Git repository, my workspace file looks like:

```
{
   "folders": [
      {
         "path": "myproject1"
      },
      {
         "path": "myproject2"
      },
      ...
      {
         "path": "myprojectN"
      },
   ],
   ...
}
```

Unfortunately, in the Git view Theia only manages Git changes in the first folder. None of the changes done in the other folders is displayed.

Is it normal ? How can I make the Git view managing several Git repositories (one per folder) like the desktop version of VSCode does ?

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on the Theia forum: https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia/issues/8291#issuecomment-668074089

The "SCM: Change repository" command allow to change the "active" Git repo in the Git view.